# Initialize and run 3rd party after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, compilation

I need to include a plugin after clicking on a button, on document ready the next code below don't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#ativar").click(function()
    {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = '//api.handtalk.me/plugin/latest/handtalk.min.js';
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//api.handtalk.me/plugin/latest/handtalk.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var ht = new HT({
        token: "a34asfdas43d4f5" //example of token
    });
</script>
```

I tried to implement this javascript above, but this don't run the script after button click. How can i approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ativar").click(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');

    script.id = 'handtalk-id';
    script.src = '//api.handtalk.me/plugin/latest/handtalk.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    $(document).find('#handtalk-id').on('load', function() {
        var ht = new HT({
            token: "a34asfdas43d4f5" //example of token
        });
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing code before the script has been downloading.

Try this

```
<script src="//api.handtalk.me/plugin/latest/handtalk.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var isScriptLoaded = setIterval(function(){
            if(window.HT){
            clearInterval(isScriptLoaded);
           var ht = new HT({
             token: "a34asfdas43d4f5" //example of token
          });
        }
    },1000);
</script>
```